# How to disable permalinks to some custom post content?

Tags: permalinks

So, I maintain a site that puts a lot of content in modals that's pulled from custom post types. The issue I'm running into if someone (like one of our team members) goes to where they think a piece of content should be they get taken to an unstyled page of the content via the content's permalink. How can I either disable the permalinks or redirect users to the right page?

Comment: Do you have control over the post types? If they're not supposed to be visited then the `public` argument should be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

When defining a custom post type with `register_post_type()` an array of arguments is passed.  Set the `public` parameter to 'false' to prevent generation of permalinks, as well as other associated actions (search, nav, et al).

Using the example from the WP Codex:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => false,
      'label'  => 'Books'
    );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type